# CSS - Display array results in GRID

Tags: css, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to display my array results in a grid.

This the code I'm currently using to display my results:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) { %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
<img src='http://localhost:5000/public/Images/<%= path[i] %>' style="height: 200px; width: 200px" alt="memes">  
</div>
</div>      
  <% } %>

</div>
```

This is how they are being displayed:

[image]

I want 3 or 4 results in a row instead of a row with a result.

Is this possible using DIV in css?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable code sample. You can see how to do that [from this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated the question. How @AlonEitan?

Comment: I have done that @MarcusParsons. Thanks

Comment: You need to put the wrapping `row` element outside of the loop

Comment: Now working thanks.